# How to make a customizable image to tumble

Tags: flash, image, tumblr, user-customization

I'm trying to make a fill in the blank image that will be customized with a user's text and then allow them to "Tumble" it right away. So it's an image that will, for e.g., say "Today, I ***_*___**", then a field underneath will allow users to enter something for the "fill in the blank", preview it for them and then allow them to post it to their Tumblr.
I found something regarding customizable images on the garfield site: http://www.garfield.com/facebook/special_3mil_strip.html
But it's using Flash, which I would like to stay away from. Is there a way to do this without using Flash while still giving users an option to post their stuff on Tumblr right away?

Answer (score 0):

[Anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Try searching. 99% of what you can ask is probably there already, one just needs to look for it.

[google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20jpg)